# Home symbol `~` not recognized in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my dockerfile, I want to copy a file from `~/.ssh` of my host machine into the container, so i worte it like this:

```
# create ssh folder and copy ssh keys from local into container
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
COPY ~/.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/
```

But when I run `docker build -t foo` to build it, it stopped with an error:

```
Step 2 : RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> db111747d125
Step 3 : COPY ~/.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/
~/.ssh/id_rsa: no such file or directory
```

It seems the `~` symbol is not recognized by dockerfile, how could I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Docker, it is not possible to copy files from anywhere on the system into the image, since this would be considered a security risk. COPY paths are always considered relative to the build context, which is current directory where you run the `docker build` command.

This is described in the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#copy

As a result, the `~` has no useful meaning, since it would try and direct you to a location which is not part of the context.

If you want to put your local `id_rsa` file into the docker, you should put it into the context first, e.g. copy it along side the Dockerfile, and refer to it that way.

Comment: If COPY can only used to copy content relative to current directory, it would definitely lost some flexibility. It's obvious not a good idea to copy the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` into the context just to make the COPY command work. But at least you've clarified my confusion, thanks mattinbits.